# Waiting for form submit to end in iframe or object html

Tags: javascript, php, object, iframe

I have in my website a object html like so:

```
 <object id="objetoPag" type="text/html" data="http://www.example.com/index.php"></object>
```

and in this tag there is a form with some inputs.
When I click the submit button inside the object tag the response will be a big XML.

how could I retrieve the XML and control when the submit has ended?

I understand that the object tag has some restrictions so I tried changing it to a iframe instead.

**UPDATE**

I used ajax like the following:

```
$http.post("http://phpfile.php",params).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
   })
```

But I am getting a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: I would do it with ajax. You submit the form with ajax and you can wait the response from the server with XML data.

Comment: thats.....a brilliant idea xD,goin to try that out

Comment: I added the ajax but now I am getting  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',

Comment: iframes and object elements have the same security restrictions, XMLHttpRequest has similar security restrictions but with a different implementation.